# Can't retrieve an array from Parse

Tags: c#, arrays, parse-platform

Minor problem here. I'm building a .NET website with C# and Parse.com as backend. I'm having some trouble getting an array out of the DB. Currently I use the following line for regular String values, which works fine:

```
string objTitle = vormingObject.Get<string>("title");
```

but when I try to retrieve an array, I get an error.

```
var periodes = vormingObject.Get<string[]>("periodes");
vorming.Periodes = periodes;
```

I've tried changing the var to string[] but that doesn't do the trick either. Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: the error:
 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.String[]'

SOLUTION: as mentioned by one of the users below:

```
 IList<string> Periodes = vormingObject.Get<IList<string>>("periodes");
```

Comment: The [docs mention `IList<T>`](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects) for certain scenarios, does that work?

Comment: derp, added the error. but no, IList doesn't work. Gonna retry just to be sure

Comment: okay nvm. It actually was IList, but the actual error was just something else. I feel stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the Parse.com API, but the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>` to type `System.String[]`

is pretty clear: the API found a `List<object>`, but it can't cast that to the requested string array for you. Change your code to:

```
var periodes = vormingObject.Get<List<object>>("periodes");
```

Then you can cast the objects to the appropriate type, for example:

```
IEnumerable<string> periodStrings = periodes.Cast<string>();
```